# How to solve the brute-force problem using associative container?

Tags: c++, associative

count the number of (a,b,c)(1≤a,b,c≤n) satisfying a^k+b^k=c^k (2≤ k ≤ 20)

How can I solve this problem by first restore all the result of a^k + b^k and then match c^k accordingly?

When I enter n = 10, the count will be 876, why will that happen?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<map>
#include<set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int count = 0;
    map<int, set<int> > hash;
    for(int k = 2; k <= 20; ++k)
    {
        set<int> s;
        hash[k] = s;
    }

    for(int c = 1; c <= n; ++c)
        for(int k = 2; k <= 20; ++k)
            hash[k].insert(pow(c,k));

    for(int k = 2; k <= 20; ++k)
        cout << "k=" << k << " -- " << hash[k].size() << endl;

    for(int k = 2; k <= 20; ++k)
    {
        for(int a = 1; a <= n; ++a)
            for(int b = 1; b <= n; ++b)
            {
                if(hash[k].find(pow(a,k) + pow(b,k)) != hash[k].end())
                    count++;
            }
    }

    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int` almost certainly does not have enough bits to represent the number `pow(10,20)`.

Comment: By the way, your algorithm is count a solution twice. For example, if a = 3 and b=4, is a solution your algorithm will consider a = 4 and b=3 as another solution. And, just completing @aschepler comments, I think `long long` will not have enough bits for `pow(10, 20)` too.

Answer (score 0):

There exists no solution for a^k+b^k=c^k for k>2.

From Wikipedia:-

In number theory **Fermat's Last Theorem** states that no three positive integers a, b, and c satisfy the equation a^n + b^n = c^n for any integer value of n greater than 2. 
The cases n = 1 and n = 2 have been known to have infinitely many solutions since antiquity
This also been proved.
So you can try to solve just for the value of k=2.

For **k=2** You can use this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-pythagorean-triplets/)